# Android ListView not refreshing after dataset changed, though I have used the Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview

I know similar questions had been asked here a couple of times, but none of them could help me with my problem, so I will just have to ask again.

What I have is an app that has a fragment that holds a ListView in the main activity and I used a **PullableListView** so that when I drag the ListView up, it will trigger the **onLoadMore()**  callback method to load more data from the server. Once data loaded, the data will be saved to a SQLiteDB and then used by the ListView to show the updated data.

The is my PullableListViewFragment.java:

```
public class PullableListViewFragment extends Fragment implements
    OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private PullToRefreshLayout ptrl;

private MissionDB mMissionDB;
private List<MissionEntity> mData;

private MissionListAdapter mAdapter;

/**
 * Specify the exact mission that will be displayed in MissionDetailActivity
 */
private int mIndexOfMission;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View pullableLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pullable_layout, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) pullableLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
    listView.setDivider(null);
    ptrl = (PullToRefreshLayout) pullableLayout.findViewById(R.id.refresh_view);
    ptrl.setOnRefreshListener(new RefreshListener());
    loadData();

    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "onCreateView Called from PullableListViewFragment");

    return pullableLayout;
}

/**
 * Initialise ListView
 */
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new MissionListAdapter(getActivity(), mData);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "onActivityCreated Called from PullableListViewFragment");
}

/**
 * Load data from db
 */
private void loadData() {
    mData = new ArrayList<>();
    mMissionDB = MissionDB.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext());
    mData = mMissionDB.loadMission();
}

/**
 * OnItemClick event
 */
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MissionDetailActivity.class);
    mIndexOfMission = mData.get((int) id).getId();
    intent.putExtra("Position", mIndexOfMission);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

And this is the RefreshListener.java:

```
public class RefreshListener implements PullToRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

private MissionDB mMissionDB = MissionDB.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext());

@Override
public void onLoadMore(final PullToRefreshLayout pullToRefreshLayout) {
    // LoadMore
    new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            /** When drag up, load more mission that is older and not out of date */
            mMissionDB.open();
            int id = mMissionDB.getMaxOrMinId("MIN");
            final JSONObject oldMission = new JSONObject();
            try {
                oldMission.put("platform", "1");
                oldMission.put("more", 0);
                oldMission.put("id", id);
                oldMission.put("size", 1);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    HttpRequest.sendHttpRequest(Constants.PULLORDRAG_TO_LOAD_MISSION_URL, oldMission, new HttpCallbackListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish(String response) {
                            MissionEntity mMission = new MissionEntity();

                            /** Save new mission to mission database */
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray missionList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("taskList");
                                for (int i = 0; i < missionList.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject mission = missionList.getJSONObject(i);
                                    mMission.setId(mission.getInt("id"));
                                    mMission.setDownloadUrl(mission.getString("appPath"));
                                    mMission.setCreateTime(mission.getString("taskId"));
                                    mMission.setImageUrl(mission.getString("appImg"));
                                    mMission.setTitleName(mission.getString("appName"));
                                    mMission.setRemainTime("Remain： 1d 11h 23m 36s");
                                    mMission.setParticipant("135");
                                    mMission.setCreator("Google");
                                    mMission.setRequirement(mission.getString("description"));
                                    mMission.setRewards("TODO");
                                    mMission.setAttention("TODO");
                                    mMission.setValidDate(mission.getString("deadline"));
                                    mMission.setAccepted("0");
                                    mMission.setCollected("0");
                                    mMission.setAccomplished("0");
                                    mMissionDB.saveMission(mMission);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Error while loading more");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            try {
                t.start();
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            pullToRefreshLayout.loadmoreFinish(PullToRefreshLayout.SUCCEED);

            //==================Update 1==================
            ListView list = (ListView) pullToRefreshLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
            List<MissionEntity> missionList = mMissionDB.loadMission();
            Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "mission size" + missionList.size());
            MissionListAdapter adapter = (MissionListAdapter) list.getAdapter();
            adapter.setData(missionList);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            //==================Update 1==================
        }
    }.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000);
}

}
```

The PullToRefreshLayout is a custom RelativeLayout that defined a inner interface **OnRefreshListener** that will be called once the **onLoadMore()** callback method is called.

The ListView I use in the Fragment is a **PullableListView** that implemented a **Pullable** interface that can drag up.

My Pullable.java:

```
public interface Pullable
{
    /**
     * If pull up is not needed, set canPullUp to false
     * 
     * @return true if the View can pull up
     */
    boolean canPullUp();
}
```

This is the fragment's layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="#f2f2f2"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp" />

<pulltorefresh.PullToRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/refresh_head"/>

    <!-- Supports all view that implemented the Pullable interface -->
    <pulltorefresh.PullableListView
        android:id="@+id/content_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <include layout="@layout/load_more"/>

</pulltorefresh.PullToRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is when the data in the SQLiteDB is changed after the onLoadMore() method, the ListView in the fragment doesn't refresh itself unless I navigate to another fragment within the same main activity and then navigate back.

I tired all the ways I can find here and none of them help.

Could anyone tell me how can I make the ListView refresh itself when the data in the SQLiteDB changed.

**[Update 1]** I've added some code in the onLoadMore() callback, the size of the data remains the same after I get some data from the server, i think this is the problem why the ListVie is not refreshing, what's interesting is if I put a `Thread.sleep(500)` before `mMission.loadMission()` the size of the data is correct and everything is fine. Any idea why?

Comment: hmm, maybe not the smartest of solutions but what I used to do was to refresh my ArrayList, reload the ArrayAdapter with the new ArrayList, then reassign the ArrayAdapter to the ListView variable -- something to that effect.

Comment: @Razgriz I've tried the way you use, it's not working as well. What I do is in the onLoadMore() callback method, after the **pullToRefreshLayout.loadmoreFinish(PullToRefreshLayout.SUCCEED);** I do manually create a new ArrayList from the database and get the instance of the ListView through findViewById, and assign the ArrayList to the adapter then set it to the ListView, and it's not working. This thing really divers me crazy.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird. Try logging the size of your ArrayList before you create you "reload" your ArrayAdapter. Maybe, just maybe, you weren't able to load the records completely...?

Comment: @Razgriz `ListView list = (ListView) pullToRefreshLayout.findViewById(R.id.content_view);
    List<MissionEntity> missionList = mMissionDB.loadMission();
    Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "mission size" + missionList.size());
    MissionListAdapter adapter = (MissionListAdapter) list.getAdapter();
    adapter.setData(missionList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);` **This is what I add after the loadMoreFinish() callback, the size is still the same after reload, have any idea why? Sorry for the format**

Answer (score 1):

In onLoadMore method, you just only load data and save into database. After load data, you should update the data source of the adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the listview. or you can notify the fragment to reload data from database.

Comment: Please see the comment of my question, I've added some code after the onLoadMore() callback, the size of the data is still the same as it used to be, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Try to add a List object in onFinish(String response), and add mMission into the list in for statement. after for statement, using  runOnUiThread() to append all the list to the date source of the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it get data when load more first. And I think your mMissionDB is changed indeed, but what about mData? Your adapter is use mData as datasource actually, so you should update mData, and call **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** to refresh the listview. Hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, please refer to my update, is it right to update the dataset this way? If right, why the dataset remains the same size?

Comment: In my opinion, insert into database may cost same time, and when you query from database the inserting has not been finished. So, you get the same date.

Comment: I think one thing. It get data from a new thread right? And you bind data at main thread. What makes you ensure that it's already get data at newThread when you update your data at mainThread. I can not make sure if it is the way you process the data, if you do as what i said above. That's might be the problem.

Comment: @L.Meng In my knowledge, I'm getting data in the Main thread but updating it in another thread. After I use Thread.join, I assume that the code that's used to get the already updated data will be executed after the worker thread that's used to gather data from the network. Isn't it like this?

Comment: @Lauren.Liuling Yes, that is the problem, then do you know how to fix this other than just let the thread sleep for some time?

Comment: @Pan. I mean that because insert option it isn't finish yet when you ask data from another thread.Your approach is right, but you didn't process time difference well. lol.....But i do not suggest to sleep ~ because you can not sure how long it cost, right?

Comment: @L.Meng Yes, I'm not sure how long will it cost, so I can only assume the process will not take too long and therefore I use Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, 1000) to be sure that it's long enough before the data get reloaded. Hopefully this will work, really can't find a better way for now.

Comment: @Pan. I think RxJava can help you easily :D   You can try it.